# docker build --build-arg with shell command in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I convert this command below to docker-compose version?

`docker build -t xxx --build-arg SSH_PRV_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" .`

I try this block below, but it does not work. Please help. Thanks.

```
xxx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        SSH_PRV_KEY: "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
```

Comment: Can you include any error message you might be seeing when running docker-compose? Also, try putting a dash before the argument: - SSH_PRV_KEY: ...

Comment: You do not want to put an ssh private key into a Docker image where anyone who can `docker history` or `docker run` can trivially extract it.  Bind-mounting it using a `volumes:` option is probably the easiest path.

Comment: @DavidMaze i use ssh private key just for building base image, not the main image.

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose doesn't undershell shell code like that. You can do it this way:

```
xxx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        SSH_PRV_KEY
```

Now, before run docker-compose, export your `SSH_PRV_KEY` env var:

```
export SSH_PRV_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
# now run docker-compose up as you normally do
```

Then `SSH_PRV_KEY` will have the right value.

Two thing you need to consider:

1. It may not work as expected if you have pass pharase in your `id_rsa`.
2. This `SSH_PRV_KEY` will actually available to docker meta data such as `docker history` or `images inspect`. To get around that you should look into multi stage build https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/. In your build steps, you use that key to do anything you want. Then in your final image, don't declare `SSH_PRV_KEY` but simply copy the result from previous image. A more specific example where you use a private key to install dependencies

   ```
   FROM based as build
   ARG SSH_PRV_KEY
   RUN echo "$SSH_PRV_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   RUN npm install # this may need access to that rsa key

   FROM node
   COPY --from=builder node_modules node_modules
   ```

Notice in second images, we don't declare `ARG` therefore we don't expose it.